# Why would a security rule prevent a read in the simulator, but not the equivalent read from a JS client?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a doc like this (all of this simplified) ...

```
myCollection -> myDoc: {
                 ...
                 roles: { "xyz123" : "reader" } // associate UIDs with privileges 
               }
```

and a rule like this...

```
match /myCollection/{doc=**} {  
  allow list: if request.auth.uid != null;
  allow read: if canRead(resource);
```

where `canRead` is defined as...

```
function canRead(res) {
  return request.auth.uid != null &&
    request.auth.uid in res.data.roles &&
    res.data.roles[request.auth.uid] == 'reader';
}
```

Using the simulator, simulating an authenticated user with UID="abcdef" (not present in the `roles` object), I see that this rule prevents a get. When the simulated UID="xyz123" (which is present in `roles`), the get is allowed.

But, in my app, performing the same experiment, reading succeeds with a UID that should not be permitted.  In other words...

```
console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid) // logs 'abcdef',  which should not be permitted
db.collection('myCollection').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
  console.log(snapshot.docs) // logs several docs, including myDoc
```

It's my understanding that the collection snapshot should not be permitted because one of the results cannot be read.  Furthermore, the returned docs actually contain the doc that should be excluded.

Can you think of any circumstances where both of these things can be true: A simulated get fails as expected, but a real get from a client succeeds despite a rule preventing it?

Comment: Without seeing the **complete** set of rules, and the specific code that goes along with those rules, it's not possible to explain why a query would be unexpectedly allowed.  There are only two generalized reasons why this might happen 1) you actually have a rule that allows the query, and it might not be the one you're looking at, 2) your code is using a server SDK initialized with a service account, which always bypasses all rules.  Or maybe 3) you didn't save the rules in the console, so they aren't actually active the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson - complete rule file posted.  The collection is Schools.  I'll show the query code also, though its a little abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the query is allowed is because of this line:

```
allow list: if request.auth.uid != null;
```

`list` is essentially queries, but not individual document gets.  `read` is both.  Since you allow `list` to all authenticated users, your query will work for all auth'd users.  The `get` from the console simulator was not affected by this line.

(Note that `read` access == `get` + `list`)